# UK first-time home buyer government programs - ISA

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, first-time-home-buyer, isa

I am currently looking for my first house to buy.

I looked at https://www.helptobuy.gov.uk/help-to-buy-isa/how-does-it-work/, The Help to Buy ISA had been closed to new accounts at midnight on 30 November 2019.

There is a Lifetime ISA which currently I can apply.

My question is:

Do I need to open a Lifetime ISA account before I purchase my first house?

And also from this website, I have to have had the lifetime ISA for at least a year to receive the bonus? https://www.which.co.uk/money/mortgages-and-property/first-time-buyers/help-to-buy/help-to-buy-isas-explained-aj3089u27r95

What are my other options to get the government bonus or help to buy programme?

Comment: From what I know, help to buy programmes aren't the same as help to buy ISAs (you can qualify for the programme without the ISA, and you have no obligation to go through a help to buy scheme if you have the ISA). Don't know much about the new LISAs, but I heard help-to-buy _schemes_ are often quite bad and it might be worth saving for a few years more and getting a regular mortgage instead of going through help-to-buy schemes. not really enough to warrant an answer, don't have any links on hand

Comment: Short of building a time machine, you aren't going to join a scheme that is now closed.  Most people bought their first house without any form of government bonus scheme.  They just saved up a deposit and took out a mortgage.